# Find the derivative of the following using the POWER RULE?

Tags: derivatives

problem:  $f(x)= 3x^2(x^2-20x^3+5) $

my answer:

$f(x) = 3x^4-60x^5+15x^2$

$ f'(x) = 3 \cdot 4x^3-60 \cdot 5x^4+15 \cdot 2x = 12x^3-300x^4+30x$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  For future reference, please do format your questions [using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I've edited this one already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Alternatively, you may use the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule):
$$(u\cdot v)'=u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$$
Let:
$$\begin{matrix} u=3x^2 & v=x^2-20x^3+5 \\ u'=6x & v'=2x-60x^2 \end{matrix}$$
This gives:
$$\begin{align} f'(x)&=\color{red}{6x(x^2-20x^3+5)}+\color{blue}{3x^2(2x-60x^2)}\\&=\color{red}{6x^3-120x^4+30x}+\color{blue}{6x^3-180x^4}\\&=-300x^4+12x^3+30x \end{align}$$
Which is the same answer you obtained.